# Why do I get a strange response from SQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have been working with SQL for a very long time, but this is the first time I've seen it.

I have a table contacts:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| client_id        | varchar(191) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| client_status    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname         | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| firstname        | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| patronymic       | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_of_birth    | date         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| sex              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| phone_mobile     | varchar(191) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| phone_home       | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_city_type    | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_city         | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_apt          | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_street_num   | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_street       | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_street_type  | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_district     | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| adr_postcode     | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email            | varchar(191) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| comment          | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have a simple query:

```
select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email 
  from contacts 
 where `client_id`="8011000000000005263" 
limit 1;
```

When I execute it, I get the following result: 
    **Empty set (0.00 sec)**

I know that this identifier is a database and I decided to experiment with the query, see the result below.

2.

```
mysql> select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from contacts where `client_id` like "%8011000000000005263%" limit 1;
Empty set (1.74 sec)
```

3. 
    mysql> select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from contacts where`client_id`=8011000000000005263 limit 1;

```
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| client_id         | lastname             | firstname | phone_mobile  | email |
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| 8011000000000004655| OSTROVKAYA           | YANA      | +111111111111| NULL  |
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.68 sec)
```

4.

```
mysql> select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from 
contacts where `client_id`= 8011000000000005263;
234 rows in set (0.83 sec) - WTF ???
```

5.

```
mysql> select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from 
contacts use index (client_id)  where `client_id`=8011000000000005263;
234 rows in set (0.90 sec) - WTF ???
```

6.

```
mysql> select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from contacts use index (client_id)  where client_id in (8011000000000005263) group by id_client;
234 rows in set (1.94 sec) - WTF ???
```

I want to provide an explanation for the last request:

```
mysql> explain select client_id, lastname, firstname, phone_mobile, email from contacts use index (client_id)  where client_id in (8011000000000005263) group by id_client;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contacts     | NULL       | index | client_id     | client_id | 576     | NULL | 1183745 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I can not understand why a simple query is not executed correctly. And how do I get the right result.

Moreover, this request is placed on the MySQL server (((

When we will be do communicate with the auxiliary table, then the request hangs for 20-30 minutes.

To be fully aware of what is happening I will provide table indexes:

```
+--------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table        | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +--------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | contacts |          1 | id               |            1 | id               | A         |     1177634 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | client_id        |            1 | client_id        | A         |     1136884 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | combo            |            1 | email            | A         |      194844 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | combo            |            2 | phone_mobile     | A         |     1165372 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | combo            |            3 | date_of_birth    | A         |     1081845 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | combo            |            4 | state            | A         |     1148369 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | email            |            1 | email            | A         |      197052 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | phone_mobile     |            1 | phone_mobile     | A         |     1127414 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | contacts |          1 | state            |            1 | state            | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +--------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Please, could not experienced developers explain to me this phenomenon of the behavior of this language.

Thank you so much! All clean code :)

Comment: Should the foreign key for client_id be an int instead of a varchar? Not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: @Bigbob556677 I have already thought about this, but unfortunately the indetifier has the letters ((

Comment: What's your table's collation?